# Клик на JS (Форма входа)

Tags: javascript

Я сделал такую вещь, есть кнопка "Войти" при нажатии на которую должна по середине экрана с транзишна появиться плавненько форма для входа. С кодом в JS я разобрался

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() { 

  setTimeout(function() { 
    document.getElementById('sign').click(); 
  }, 2000); 

});


function doFunction() {
 
}
```

В `doFunction` нужно написать саму функцию появления формы, но вот как это всё реализовать в связке с CSS? Т.е. ставлю блоку `display: none;`, а как с помощью JS поменять его на `display: block`? (отобразить)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В функцию дописать `document.getElementById("id_form").style.display = "block";`
 где `id_form` -это id формы, которую нужно показать

Comment: Да, про id формы я знаю, очень помогли, спасибо!

Comment: но лучше было бы добавлять класс форме, который уже задает форме display:block; так можно было бы добавить красивой анимации

Comment: Ещё интересует такой вопрос, по поводу затемнения при появлении формы. То-есть затемняется всё кроме самого блока.

Comment: Сделайте один общий блок. Добавьте в него черный блок с прозрачностью(background-color:rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)), абсолютно или фиксированно спозиционируйте, и сделайте на весь экран. и в этот общий блок перенести саму форму. и просто сделайте ее поверх затемненного блока. и в самой функции тогда показывайте общий блок

Comment: Спасибо большое :)